# Source to Destination Steps

Tags: excel, vba

I am having two columns namely Source and Destination. I looking for some VBA to find the path from source to destination.

```
Source  Destination
1. MW   PW
2. MW   Shdn
3. PW   MW
4. PW   Circ
5. Circ Run
6. Circ PW
7. Run  Circ
8. Run  Shdn
9. Shdn MW
```

As an example. If I select  Sourse: MW and  Destination : Run. then i should get the results as below.

```
1. MW_PW
2. PW_Circ
3. Circ_Run
```

I tried multiple possibilities like dijkstra's , DFS algorithms but I could't produce the desired results.

Input

```
Source(colum A) Destination(CoulmB)
1. MW          PW
2. MW          Shdn
3. PW          MW
4. PW          Circ
5. Circ        Run
6. Circ        PW
7. Run         Circ
8. Run         Shdn
9. Shdn        MW
```

Selection

```
source : MW
Dest : Run
```

Output

```
1. MW_PW
2. PW_Circ
3. Circ_Run
```

Comment: Is quite clear what you are trying to achieve, however it would be a great start to show what you have tried. Also, are these all the possible combinations? Or just a sample?